# Spring Junit4 Testing error : no DataSource specified

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, junit4

Hello I am a college student living in Korea.
I've been studying the process and I'm getting an error during the unit testing (Junit) of the project I'm working on

I tried Googleing for 3 days, but it did not work out. so, I need help.

This works well for UserDaoTest. However, one method of BoardDaoTest is not tested. I attach my source code here.

1. JdbcTemplate.java

   ```
    public class JdbcTemplate extends JdbcDaoSupport {
         private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcTemplate.class);

         public static Connection conn;
         public PreparedStatement pstmt;
         public PreparedStatement pstmt2;
         public ResultSet rs;

         @PostConstruct
         public void initialize() {
           DataSource ds = getDataSource();
           logger.info("get Data Source success!");
           conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);
           logger.info("Conn = " + conn);
           logger.info("database initialized success!");
         } { ... }
   ```
2. applicationContext.xml

   ```
   <context:annotation-config />

   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:application-properties.xml" />

   <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="viser.service.ApplicationContextProvider" />

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
       p:driverClassName="${database.driverClassName}" 
       p:url="${database.url}"
       p:username="${database.username}" 
       p:password="${database.password}" 
   />

   <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="viser.service.support.jdbc.JdbcTemplate"
       p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
   />

   <bean id="userDAO" class="viser.dao.user.UserDAO">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="boardDAO" class="viser.dao.board.BoardDAO">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>
   ```
3. UserDAOTest.java ( Successful testing )

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
   public class UserDAOTest {

     @Autowired
     private UserDAO userDAO;
     private User user;

     @Before
     public void setUp() {
       user = UserTest.TEST_USER;
     }

     @After
     public void returns() throws SQLException {
       userDAO.removeUser(user.getUserId());
     }

     @Test
     public void crud() throws Exception {
      { ... }
     }

     @Test
     public void getWhenNotExsitUser() throws Exception {
      { ... }
     }
   ```
4. BoardDAOTest.java (crud() -> success, getList() -> fail)

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
   public class BoardDAOTest {
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BoardDAOTest.class);

    public static Board TEST_BOARD = new Board("TEST_BOARD", 
   `ProjectDAOTest.TEST_PROJECT.getProjectName());`
             @Autowired
             private BoardDAO boardDAO;
             private ProjectDAO projectDAO;

             @Before
             public void setup() throws SQLException {
               boardDAO = new BoardDAO();
               projectDAO = new ProjectDAO();
               projectDAO.addProject(ProjectDAOTest.TEST_PROJECT);
             }

             @After
             public void returns() throws SQLException {
               projectDAO.removeProject(ProjectDAOTest.TEST_PROJECT.getProjectName());
             }

             @Test
             public void crud() throws SQLException {
               {...}
             }

             @Test
             public void getList() throws SQLException {
               logger.debug("list : {}", boardDAO.getBoardList(ProjectDAOTest.TEST_PROJECT.getProjectName()));  assertNotNull(boardDAO.getBoardList(ProjectDAOTest.TEST_PROJECT.getProjectName()));
         }
   ```

[(errorImageFile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7aGg.png)

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code:

1. You are defining your own `viser.service.support.jdbc.JdbcTemplate`. This is bad practice. Use the existing Spring's [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).
2. In your Test class in the `@Before` method you are manually initializing your DAOs: `new BoardDAO() / new ProjectDAO()`. This is defeating the purpose of doing Spring Integration testing. Use the existing `@Autowired` method to get them from the Test Context instead.

Comment: Thank you but I don't resolve No DataSource specified error.. : (

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing the Autowired DAOs with your own initialized ones which are missing the datasource. You are doing so in your setup method. That's your issue.

Remove the custom ones from that setup method; or remove the Autowired annotation and ensure your setup method constructs them correctly.